# Using Jest spyOn a module that is initiated

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

Within an ExpresS API I'm using the Postmark library to send an email, which is initiated like this:

```
var postmark = require("postmark");
var client = new postmark.Client("aaaa-bbbbb-cccc");
```

And then used to send a password reset mail later on with:

```
client.sendEmailWithTemplate(
    // Options here
);
```

Now, I would like to test this function has been called, but I have difficulties finding out how to mock/spy on this.

I have tried the following (simplified):

```
const request = require("supertest");
const app = require("../server/app");

const postmark = require("postmark");
jest.mock("postmark");

describe("API Tests", () => {
    test("it should give a reset link when requesting with existing e-mail address", () => {
        return request(app)
        .post("/api/auth/passwordreset")
        .send({
            email: "user1@test.test"
        })
        .then(response => {
            expect(postmark.Client).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });

});
```

This works, but it's only testing if postmark has been used, since I can't figure out how to actually test the `client.sendEmailWithTemplate` method

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

EDIT: following up on @samanime answer I created a repo to illustrate the 'challenge'

https://github.com/Hyra/jest_test_example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specifically mock out the `Client` function that is returned by the mocked `postmark` to return an object with mocked functions.

In Jest, you can provide specific mocking code for a `node_modules` by creating a folder named `__mocks__` at the same level as `node_modules`, i.e.,

```
/project-root
  /node_modules
  /__mocks__
```

Note, that is two underscores on each side.

In there, make a function named `<package_name>.js` (in your case, `postmark.js`). It will then load whatever is exported by that when you use the `mock`.

In that file, you can mock it out as needed. Something like this would probably work:

```
// global jest
module.exports = {
  Client: jest.fn(() => ({
      sendEmailWithTemplate: jest.fn(() => {})
  }))
};
```

It doesn't have to be as compact as this, but basically it makes `postmark` have a function called `Client` which returns an object that has a functiono called `sendEmailWithTemplate`, both of which are mocks/spys.

Then you can just check if `postmark.Client.sendEmailWithTemplate` was called.

The one gotcha is you'll need to be sure to reset all of these in between tests. You could do this manually in your `beforeEach()`, but if you are going to reuse it, I like to add an extra function named `__reset()` which will reset the code and just call that:

```
// global jest
const mockedPostmark = {
  Client: jest.fn(() => ({
      sendEmailWithTemplate: jest.fn(() => {})
  }))
};

mockedPostmark.__reset = () => {
  mockedPostmark.Client.mockClear();
  mockedPostmark.Client.sendEmailWithTemplate.mockClear();
};

module.exports = mockedPostmark;
```

You can add additional functions as needed as well.

Comment: Since these oneline comments don't help much, I created a repo to illustrate and reproduce the issue i have: https://github.com/Hyra/jest_test_example

Comment: I ended up extracting the mail functionality into a seperate module which made it possible to mock and spy easier. I'll accept your answer as it led me to the right direction Thanks!